# Explain this behavior: ListView + checkbox + DataPager + Viewstate off = Exception. Add another checkbox => works

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, viewstate, datapager

I have a ListView with viewstate off, Data Pager, and a LinqDataSource. There is one checkbox inside the ItemTemplate of the ListView. When clicking on any of the DataPager buttons I get an exception "Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page."

*Page markup*

http://pastebin.com/qbnJQtm0

*Codebehind*

http://pastebin.com/MFGnAWL4

I can fix the problem by enabling the ViewState, however I need to keep it off. A coworker of mine has given me a solution to fix the problem: adding this line to the ItemTemplate fixes the problem

*Full code*

http://pastebin.com/ZC9k9pre

I'm glad my code works now but I'd like to know why second hidden checkbox with Checked=true state fixes the problem.

Any ideas?